# Meta-analysis of regression slope parameter- what is sampling variance?

Tags: r, regression-coefficients, meta-analysis

**Goal**: Meta-analysis of a regression parameter.

My effect size is the slope coefficient of a line, I also have the standard error of this slope. For a given treatment within a given study, the slope comes from:
$$
Y_T-Y_C
$$
regressed on
$$
(Y_T+Y_C)/2
$$
where $Y_T$ and $Y_C$ are yield in the treatment and control.

**Approach**

If this is in R it looks like:

```
dat <- data.frame(id=c(1:3),
              study = c(1, 2, 3), 
              n1i = c(25, 40, 50), #n for treatment
              n2i = c(25, 40, 50), #n for control
              yi = c(2.167, 2.892, 2.175), #effect size
              sei = c(0.111, 0.102, 0.063))#standard error of effect size
dat$vi=dat$sei*dat$sei #sampling variance

rma.mv(yi, vi, random = ~ 1|study/id, data=dat) #note: I'm using rma.mv because my real data has multiple $y_i$ per study.
```

**Question**

Is finding the study *i* variance as easy as squaring the standard error of the slopes (like above)? If not, what is the calculation I should use as within-study sampling variance and therefore for study weighting?

Comment: These are some big questions - perhaps break your question down to ask one at a time?

Comment: Since this is a mixture of statistical issues and advice about the metafor program you might be better on the https://stat.ethz.ch/mailman/listinfo/r-sig-meta-analysis// mailing list where both are on topic. Browse the archives of the list first as similar topics come up there quite often and you may be able to narrow this down a bit before posting.

Comment: Edited to focus on only obtaining sampling variance when I have slope and from standard error of slope.